# Update partial field on Kafka sink mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I use avro schema with the schema

```
    {
  "namespace": "me.escoffier.quarkus",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Footballer",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": ["null","string"],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "club",
      "type": ["null","string"],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

In Mongo, I have existence data as:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60eeaeace1a32853aad7df0a"), "id" : "2", "name" : "Messi", "club" : "Barca" }
```

When I send an Avro object: `Footballer player = Footballer.newBuilder().setId("2").setClub("MU").build();`

My expected result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60eeaeace1a32853aad7df0a"), "id" : "2", "name" : "Messi", "club" : "MU" }
```

but actually:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60eeaeace1a32853aad7df0a"), "id" : "2", "name" : null, "club" : "MU" }
```

This is my kafka connector sink config:

```
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
document.id.strategy.overwrite.existing=true
writemodel.strategy=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy
topics=mongo-sink-test
collection=DeviceDB
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://schema_registry:8081
database=omniVista
document.id.strategy=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy
document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list=id
connection.uri=mongodb://root:rootpassword@mongo:27017
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type=AllowList
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

So, please help me config correctly

Answer (score 1):

You've built a new record with a null name.

You should verify that these properties do what you want because it appears you have configured the connector to replace/overwrite all documents with the same ID, not "update"

```
document.id.strategy.overwrite.existing=true
writemodel.strategy=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy
```

Disclaimer: I have no experience with the Mongo connector

Comment: How I can change configs for updating?

Comment: I don't have experience with the Mongo connector, but I would start with setting the first field I mentioned to `false` (which is the default). Otherwise,  [try reading its config documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/master/kafka-sink-properties/), or [file an issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/KAFKA/issues/?filter=allopenissues)

Comment: @OneCricketeer setting it to false, throws error: *Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Could not build the WriteModel,the value document does not contain an _id field of type BsonDocument which holds the business key fields.

 If you are including an existing `_id` value in the business key then ensure `document.id.strategy.overwrite.existing=true`.*

Comment: In my case, i've written  `_id` field explicitly on every insertion into the monogdb first, but when it comes to update, via sink connector, it throws above error.

Comment: @y_159 I am not neither a developer or user of this connector, so I am unsure of the correct settings to generate an "update by id" operation

Comment: I used `UpdateOneTimestampsStrategy` write model strategy with document overwrite as `false` and it worked, I can update any field in the record on the basis of `_id` which is assigned explicitly in my case. In case of `monogdb` generating it implicitly, the same solution doesn't work. It has to do something with the `ObjectId` of the unique id it is creating.

Comment: In case you've already declared any field to be unique explicitly, you can simply use writemodel strategy as `ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy` and it'll work as shown in the docs too https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/master/kafka-sink-postprocessors/#:~:text=db.collection.createIndex(%7B%20%22flight_no%22%3A%201%2C%20%22airport_code%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%7B%20unique%3A%20true%20%7D).

Comment: @y_159 Feel free to provide a separate answer if you have something that works for you